# LATERAL VIEW explode funtion in hive

Tags: view, hive, explode, hiveddl, lateral

I am trying to export data from excel into a hive table, while doing so, i have a column 'ABC' which has values like '1,2,3'.
I used the lateral view explode function but it does not does anything to my data.

Following is my code snippet :
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
id  string,
brand   string,
data_name   string,
name    string,
address string,
country string,
flag    string,
sample_list array  )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'location' INTO TABLE
table_name ;

***output sample:***

## id  brand   data_name   name    address  country    flag    sample_list

19  1   ABC     SQL         ABC     Cornstarch  IN       1      ["[1,2,3]"]

***then i do:***
select *  from franchise_unsupress LATERAL VIEW explode(SEslist) SEslist as final_SE;

***output sample:***

## id  brand   data_name   name    address  country    flag    sample_list

19  1   ABC     SQL         ABC     Cornstarch  IN       1      [1,2,3]

***I also tried:***
select *  from franchise_unsupress lateral view explode(split(SEslist,',')) SEslist AS final_SE ;
***but got an error:***

FAILED: ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardListObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector

***whereas, what i need is:***

## id  brand   data_name   name    address  country    flag    sample_list

19  1   ABC     SQL         ABC     Cornstarch  IN       1      1
19  1   ABC     SQL         ABC     Cornstarch  IN       1      2
19  1   ABC     SQL         ABC     Cornstarch  IN       1      3

Any help will be greatly appreciated! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that array is recognized in a wrong way and loaded as a single element array  `["[1,2,3]"]`. It should be  `[1,2,3]` or  `["1","2","3"]` (if it is `array<string>`)

When creating table, specify delimiter for collections:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide my answer.
The issue was with the input that was being provided. My input txt file had [] around the input value. They had to be removed and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a bit ambiguous in reference to your original question. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include the specific example of what this looked like before and what you changed it to?